# Insert custom HTML in page DOM with Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager

I've implemented GTM on my website. I'm wondering if is possible to add custom HTML/JS in a specific position of the DOM.

This is what I've inserted in my page:

```html
<div class="myClass">
    <p>foo</p>
    <script>
        dataLayer.push({'event':'myEvent'})
    </script>   
</div>
```

and on GTM I've set up a tag with this html:

```html
<div class="test">this is a test</div>
<iframe src="www.foo.com" />
```

which is triggered on `myEvent`.

Unfortunatly this is not working correctly, my tag is inserted at the bottom of my web page and not inside the `myClass` div.

Am I doing something wrong or this is just not allowed by GTM?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Not allowed" is perhaps a bit strong (as you can see it works to some extent), but tags that change visual aspects of the page are generally not recommended.

If you want to insert HTML at a specific location it would be better to create the element dynamically via javascript and append it to an existing element, so your HTML tag would look something like (untested):

```
<script>
var myDiv = document.createElement('div');
myDiv.setAttribute('class','test');
var container = document.querySelector('.myClass');
container.append(myDiv);
</script>
```

You would need to make sure that the element you append to is unique (if possible add an id rather than a class name). Tags are executed asynchronously, so it's a bit hard to say at which point in the loading process the HTML is appended (this will cause a reflow in the DOM which is an expensive operation for the client, so you do not want to do this too often).

Comment: This is probably the right way to do it. The problem is that the one who will manage the GTM tags is not a developer, he just want to "copy/paste" from the ads console where the HTML snippet come from. Anyway, I think I can mark your answer as accepted. Thank you.

Comment: @Eike , so why is it when we do it this way, scripts don't load? I mean , i have a script that adds a js var, then a div with a specific id and then a js bundle that uses that div , when I do this using GTM this does not work, only when hardcoded